# EDITLogBack Syslog not working java

Tags: java, ubuntu, logging, syslog

I have wrote a simple project to run the log in Ubuntu by follow this [example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-syslog-example/).

**ApplicationStarter**

```
package com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample;

import com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.IMessageTransmitter;
import com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.kiwi.KiwiMessageTransmitterImpl;
import com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.rsyslog.RsyslogMessageTransmitterImpl;

public class ApplicationStarter {

    /**
     * Main method
     */
    public static void main( final String[] args ) {

        final IMessageTransmitter kiwiMessageTransmitter = new KiwiMessageTransmitterImpl();
        kiwiMessageTransmitter.send( "I am learning to send message to Syslog server" );

        final IMessageTransmitter rsyslogMessageTransmitter = new RsyslogMessageTransmitterImpl();
        rsyslogMessageTransmitter.send( "Logback can easily send message to Syslog server" );
    }
}
```

**KiwiMessageTransmitterImpl**

```
package com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.kiwi;

import com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.IMessageTransmitter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class KiwiMessageTransmitterImpl implements IMessageTransmitter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( KiwiMessageTransmitterImpl.class );

    @Override
    public void send( final String message ) {
        LOGGER.info( "Hello! My message is : {}", message );
    }
}
```

**RsyslogMessageTransmitterImpl**

```
package com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.rsyslog;

import com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.IMessageTransmitter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class RsyslogMessageTransmitterImpl implements IMessageTransmitter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( RsyslogMessageTransmitterImpl.class );

    @Override
    public void send( final String message ) {
        LOGGER.info( "Hello! My message is : {}", message );
    }
}
```

**IMessageTransmitter**

```
package com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message;

public interface IMessageTransmitter {

    void send(final String message);
}
```

When I run my project , I get the same things! The 
message from Java are not sending to `syslog` !

Here the **logback.xml**. I put in resources folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="KIWI" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>localhost</syslogHost>
        <facility>LOCAL0</facility>
        <suffixPattern>%thread: %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</suffixPattern>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RSYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <!-- Ubuntu Server host name -->
        <syslogHost>centol</syslogHost>
        <facility>LOCAL1</facility>
        <suffixPattern>%thread: %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</suffixPattern>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.kiwi" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="KIWI" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.rsyslog" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="RSYSLOG" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

I use this command to examine `syslog`. The `syslog` output looked correctly now. Unfortunately, the message send from Netbeans(JAVA) still not receiving in the `syslog`.

Try `cat /var/log/syslog` (small part of the output)

```
Jun  6 23:37:26 xxx whoopsie[1040]: [23:37:26] online
Jun  6 23:37:26 xxx avahi-daemon[1023]: Registering new address record for 2001:e68:4424:afab:c31f:c843:2351:c58 on wlp6s0.*.
Jun  6 23:37:28 xxx dhclient[19397]: XMT: Solicit on wlp6s0, interval 4340ms.
Jun  6 23:37:32 xxx dhclient[19397]: XMT: Solicit on wlp6s0, interval 9080ms.
Jun  6 23:37:41 xxx dhclient[19397]: XMT: Solicit on wlp6s0, interval 17540ms.
Jun  6 23:37:59 xxx dhclient[19397]: XMT: Solicit on wlp6s0, interval 34190ms.
Jun  6 23:38:09 xxx NetworkManager[1013]: <warn>  [1496763489.9447] dhcp6 (wlp6s0): request timed out
Jun  6 23:38:09 xxx NetworkManager[1013]: <info>  [1496763489.9448] dhcp6 (wlp6s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jun  6 23:38:09 xxx NetworkManager[1013]: <info>  [1496763489.9456] dhcp6 (wlp6s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 19397
Jun  6 23:38:09 xxx NetworkManager[1013]: <info>  [1496763489.9456] dhcp6 (wlp6s0): state changed timeout -> done
user@xxx:/$
```

Not sure is it because of the syslogHost and facility.

Comment: The article explains that in your `logback.xml` you need to configure a `ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender`. Have you done that?

Comment: @HuguesMoreau any idea ?

Comment: No but I upvoted your answer, nice of you to provide the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FINALLY** I get it to work! What a nightmare...

I follow [Rsyslog : Output Logs to Remote Host](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=rsyslog) to configure `Syslog` server.

Go to **rsyslog.conf**

```
sudo vim etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Uncomment these two lines.

```
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
```

Save and exit. Then Restart service.

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

MAGIC !